# Responsively sizing a sprite

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I'm using: Bootstrap 3.1.1, jQuery 1.11

What I'm trying to do: Use a sprite for various category icons and position it via CSS.

On xs devices (phones) I want to keep 3 of these on each row, as I am on small medium & large devices.

However, the size of each icon is 200x200. And I'm not sure how to responsively size a sprite image like this. If I change #category-icons a.hand-tools width & height, it only shows a small section of the sprite instead of sizing the sprite.

The sprite can be found at: http://www.amleo.com/images/art/mobile-category-icons.png

Any ideas, guys? Should I use 2 different sprites, and use the CSS below in media queries to use a different sprite for tablets & phones? I'm not sure at all.

Looking for the easiest solution that works, of course.

JS Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/43rxf/

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="/hand-tools/c/P01/" title="Hand Tools" class="hand-tools" target="_blank">Hand Tools</a>
</div>

#category-icons a {
    background: url(/images/art/mobile-category-icons.png) no-repeat;
    margin-right: 11px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
}

#category-icons a.hand-tools {
    background-position: -30px -30px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 32px;
}
```

Comment: i use background size to decrease the overall size of the sprite the n fit it into position

Comment: @Mr.coder I tried that, and that didn't do much.
At 100%: http://i.imgur.com/6lZiEvg.png
At 700%: http://i.imgur.com/EsaOLby.png
They eventually get side by side at 700%, but they still overlap eachother. I'm doing 3 icons to a row, you can't even see the 3rd icon there.

Comment: then if your site is responsive then you have to use individual images

Comment: JS Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/43rxf/

Comment: if you are using media screen to detect the change in scree size then it possible else use singular images for each div(this method will work and save you time)

Comment: Why not use a font icon if you only need 1-color images? (http://icomoon.io is a great service)

Answer (score 0):

Sprites are indeed very hard to maintain even if not responsive.

You can use this [plugin](http://tobyj.net/responsive-sprites/) to make responsive sprite :)